# Is "as ... go[es]" correct, and what is this form called?

Tags: grammar, expressions

I'm a German native speaker. Think I remember hearing an expression of the form "as ... go[es]" somewhere. Do I remember it correctly? Is the meaning I deduced correct?

> Example:
> **As** mirrors **go**, this stirred water surface is a rather useless one.
> = When comparing this stirred water surface to other mirrors, it turns out to be rather useless.

Tried to search books and the internet for this expression, but the gap and the common words "as" and "go" make it impossible to track it down in examples or find it in grammar sections. Does this form have a name, that would enable me to look it up in a dictionary?

Comment: [Cambridge Dictionary](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/go) includes the usage: << **as ... go [ / goes / went]**: in comparison with most other things of a particular type, especially when you do not think that type of thing is very good:
• _It was quite a good film, as horror films go._
• _I suppose the concert was OK, as these things go_. >>

Comment: I sympathize and have a general suggestion. When you want to find a definition and/or usage examples of some expression that includes a verb, it's good to start by looking up the meaning of the verb.  There will be lots of different expressions listed, all under the general heading of that verb.  I think you would get the hang of how English-only dictionaries are organized more easily if you buy a second-hand dictionary in hard copy, and do some wandering-reading of it for fun sometimes.  Sample several in a second-hand bookstore and choose one you like (typesetting, pronunciation key, etc.).

Comment: Fully accept the closing. Thanks for the help and the suggestions anyway! @aparente001, this is a helpful hint and I will follow your advise. I indeed found it incredibly hard to dig up certain kinds of expressions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Edwin Ashworth wrote in a comment:

> [Cambridge Dictionary](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/go) includes, under the entry for the verb *go*, the usage:
>
> > **as ... go [ / goes / went]**: in comparison with most other things of a particular type, especially when you do not think that type of thing is very good:
> >
> > - *It was quite a good film, as horror films go.*
> > - *I suppose the concert was OK, as these things go*.